# ORA-00936: missing expression, Group by Date only on a Datetime column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with column-like:

> CREATED_DATE  DATE

My query such as:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(TOTAL), CREATED_DATE
FROM RKAP_REALISASI
WHERE ACCOUNT = '21157' AND CREATED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('9/5/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/31/2018','MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY ACCOUNT, CREATED_DATE
```

This will group by the full DateTime, including hours and minutes. I wish to make the group by, only by the date MM/DD/YYYY and do some SUM to its, not by the MM/DD/YYYY/hh/mm/ss.

So far I've tried with:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(TOTAL), DATE(CREATED_DATE)
FROM RKAP_REALISASI
WHERE ACCOUNT = '21157' AND CREATED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('9/5/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/31/2018','MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY ACCOUNT, DATE(RKAP_REALISASI.CREATED_DATE)
```

But it fails, ORA-00936: missing expression.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TRUNC` function to get only date not hour, min, sec.

```
SELECT account, SUM(total), TRUNC(created_date)
FROM rkap_realisasi
WHERE account = '21157' 
    AND TRUNC(created_date) BETWEEN TO_DATE('9/5/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('10/31/2018','MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY account, TRUNC(created_date)
ORDER BY account, TRUNC(created_date);
```